# UNIX(AIX): How can i list all files in a directory that is NOT in a list

Tags: unix, find, aix

I am looking for a way to list the contents of a directory on a UNIX system, that does not appear in a predefined "exclude" list.

Say i have a dir:

```
dir1
    dir1-1
        test1
        test2
        test3
    dir1-2
        test4
        test5
```

and an "exclude list" as such:

```
dir1/dir1-1/test1
dir1/dir1-2/test5
```

I am interested in outputting

```
dir1/dir1-1/test2
dir1/dir1-1/test3
dir1/dir1-2/test4
```

And the actual command will be with both an exclude list and a directory structure with thousands of files, so performance is a bit of an issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude them with the `!` operator:

```
find . -type f ! \( -path "./dir1-1/test1" -o -path "./dir1-2/test5" \)
```

Note we are hardcoding the excludee path from the `.`. So in case you execute it from another place you will need to add the corresponding path. Or, better, use full paths like:

```
find /your/path/ -type f ! \( -path "/your/path/dir1-1/test1" -o -path "/your/path/dir1-2/test5" \)
```